# Program to alert me whenever my webcam is turned on

Tags: windows, webcam

I am looking for a program to alert me (notification window, email, etc.) whenever my webcam is turned on.

If possible, it would log when the webcam is turned on and off.

- Ideally free
- Running on Windows, ideally supporting Windows 7 and 8.1

Comment: I don't have a suggestion for you, but have you considered just using a piece of electrical tape?

Comment: Sometimes I want to use the webcam.

Comment: Then you peel back the tape, and replace it when done.

Comment: The user is quadraplegic.

Comment: Well, there goes the hardware solution. Sorry for the assumption, but I have seen lots of people who are privacy-sensitive simply use a piece of electrical tape in case the camera is activated accidentally or unknowingly.

Comment: I don't get the use case. Who is turning the camera on and how? Who wants to be notified - the one who turns on or someone else?

Comment: @Mawg Who is turning the camera on -> attacker or some dumb program.  Who wants to be notified -> the computer user.

Comment: That makes it *much* clearer. There's a camera API in Windwos 8 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj571202(v=vs.105).aspx), but not in 7, which has a sensor API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318953(v=vs.85).aspx).  This will probably make it harder to find a suitable app, unless you restrict it to one version. The same goes for coding your own.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Not sure if this is what you want.. But Kaspersky Antivirus can block access to webcams. When an application tries to access the webcam, Kaspersky explicitly asks the user permission. There must be similar features with other antivirus solutions too

Comment: @AswinPJ Sounds like a good option, you are welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Kapersky Antivirus](http://www.kaspersky.com) can [block access to webcam](http://support.kaspersky.com/10978). Whenever an application tries to access the webcam, Kaspersky explicitly asks the user's permission. Kaspersky also allows you to `always allow` some applications to use the webcam and `always deny` others. I am not sure if other antivirus software provide the same functionality, but it is most likely that they do.