# Checking if webcam is on

Tags: windows-8, webcam

This is similar question to [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/program-to-alert-me-whenever-my-webcam-is-turned-on)

But I'm looking for application which alerts on **Windows 8.1** (for webcam assembled in Dell Inspiron 5000/3000 series).

It would be nice if app would be free and gather logs.

Comment: Hi jsDoggy! This question is indeed *very very* similar to Franck's question... How about setting a bounty on Franck's question when you get more points? That would certainly get you more answers.

Comment: How can I do it? I'm a newbie to stackexchange :)
Moreover, if I could ask here: what does it mean that my question is a duplicate of another (but I'm asking for soft for another OS)?

Comment: Meanwhile I modified the existing question to cover Windows 8.1

Comment: But it doesn't mean something "wrong" to me?

Comment: Nothing wrong I think, the question just benefits from being a bit more open :-)